# Generate matrices using positive integer solutions of the indefinite equation

Tags: r

I asked a question similar to this one previously. But this one little more tricky. I have POSITIVE INTEGER solutions(previously NON-NEGATIVE solutions) matrix(say `A`) to the indefinite equation `x1+x2+x3 = 8`. Also, I have another matrix(say `B`) with columns

```
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1
```

I want to generate matrices using rows of `A` and the columns of `B`.

For an example, let `(2,2,4)` is the one solution(one row) of the matrix `A`. In this case, I just cannot use `rep`. So I tried to generate all the three column matrices from matrix `B` and then try to apply `rep`, but couldn't figure that out. I use the following lines to generate lists of all three column matrices.

```
cols <- combn(ncol(B), 3, simplify=F, FUN=as.numeric)
M3 <- lapply(cols, function(x) cbind(B[,x]))
```

For an example, `cols[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3`

Then, the columns of my new matrix would be

```
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Columns of this new matrix are the multiples of columns of B. i.e., first column 2-times, second column 2-time and third column 4-times. I want to use this procedure all the rows of matrix A. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?rep(x, times)` says;

> if times is a vector of the same length as x (after replication by
>   each), the result consists of x[1] repeated times[1] times, x[2]
>   repeated times[2] times and so on.

Basic idea is;

```
B <- matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), byrow = T, nrow = 2)
cols <- combn(ncol(B), 3, simplify=F, FUN=as.numeric)

a1 <- c(2, 2, 4)    
cols[[1]]  # [1] 1 2 3
rep(cols[[1]], a1)   # [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3

B[, rep(cols[[1]], a1)]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
```

```
testA <- rbind(c(2,2,4), c(2,1,5), c(2,3,3))

 ## apply(..., lapply(...)) approach (output is list in list)
apply(testA, 1, function(x) lapply(cols, function(y) B[, rep(y, x)]))

 ## other approach using combination of indices
ind <- expand.grid(ind_cols = 1:length(cols), ind_A = 1:nrow(testA))
col_ind <- apply(ind, 1, function(x) rep(cols[[x[1]]], testA[x[2],]))

lapply(1:ncol(col_ind), function(x) B[, col_ind[,x]])   # output is list

library(dplyr)
apply(col_ind, 2, function(x) t(B[, x])) %>% matrix(ncol = 8, byrow=T)  # output is matrix
```